# Ansible to rename a file only if exists

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-playbook, devops

I need to rename /jp/Test to /jp/test only if /jp/Test exists , otherwise i dont need to perform this task. if Both exists i need to merge both into /jp/test

I get below error

```
{"msg": "The conditional check 'item.1.stat.exists == false and item.2.stat.exists == true' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.1.stat.exists == false and item.2.stat.exists == true): dict object has no element 1\n\nThe error appears to be in
```

Playbook:

```
hosts: test
gather_facts: false
vars:
  hostsfiles:
    - /jp/test
    - /jp/Test
    


  tasks:
    - name: Check if file exists
      stat:
        path: "{{ item}}"
      with_items: "{{ hostsfiles }}"
      register: jpresult

    - name: test
      shell: mv "{{item.2.stat.path}}" /jp/test
      with_items:
        - "{{ jpresult.results }}"
      when: item.1.stat.exists == false and item.2.stat.exists == true
```

Comment: There seems to be tasks missing from this playbook. What are you doing when both files exist?

Comment: When both exists i merge it into /jp/test

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"?

Comment: I merge the contents of /jp/Test into /jp/test

Comment: You said that already and it is too vague to be understandable. Please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a working solution. Note that you may want to set the owner/permissions on the file created by `blockinfile`, and that `blockinfile` will add insertion anchors around the inserted text in the destination file. Both of these can be configured (see [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html))

```yaml
- name: Some very cool play
  hosts: test
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    destination_path: /jp/test
    legacy_path: /jp/Test
  tasks:
    - name: Check if legacy file exists
      stat:
        path: "{{ legacy_path }}"
      register: legacy_status

    - name: Move contents of legacy file to destination file
      when: legacy_status.stat.exists is true
      block:
        # Note that there is currently no module to read the contents of a
        # file on the remote, so using "cat" via command is the best alternative
        - name: Read contents of legacy file
          command:
            cmd: cat {{ legacy_path }}
          register: legacy_contents
          changed_when: false

        - name: Add contents of legacy file to destination file
          blockinfile:
            path: "{{ destination_path }}"
            state: present
            block: "{{ legacy_contents.stdout }}"
            # This ensures the file is created if it does not exist, 
            # saving an extra task to rename the file if necessary
            create: true  

    - name: Remove legacy file
      file:
        path: "{{ legacy_path }}"
        state: absent
```

The error you have there is due to the loop variable not being a list, but a dictionary object. When you invoke `loop: "{{ jpresult.results }}"` (note, see [`loop` vs `with_`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop)) the value of `{{ item }}` for each iteration of the loop is a single item in the list, rather than the full list. To access the stat value of the current loop index you can use `item.stat`, or to access the stat of a different iteration you can use `jpresult.results.N.stat` (where `N` is the index you want to access).